# Pattern placeholder for zero or more matching items in list

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm working through the exercises in Stephen Wolfram's book "An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language." In Chapter 32 on "Patterns", Exercise 32.1 is "Find lists beginning with 1 and ending with 9 in IntegerDigits[Range[1000]]." and the answer given is `Cases[IntegerDigits[Range[1000]], {1, __, 9}]`. However, this produces only the lists for 3-digit numbers like 109, but it doesn't produce 19, `{{1},{19}}`, the only 2-digit number in the range. To get a complete list (including 19), I use `Intersection[Cases[IntegerDigits[Range[1000]], {1, __}],  Cases[IntegerDigits[Range[1000]], {__, 9}]]`. I also tried`Cases[IntegerDigits[Range[1000]], {1, x_: Nothing, 9}]`,which produces the correct list in this case (including 19), but fails for cases where the list contains numbers with 4 or more digit numbers.
My question: instead of '__', which matches any number of items but fails to find lists where there is no item in that slot, is there a pattern-matching symbol that will find zero or more items at a pattern slot?

Comment: Yes, `BlankNullSequence[]`, `___`. Its documentation page is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html).